# PMU counters in ARM11

Tags: arm, bare-metal

I am programming raspbery `pi model b ARM1176 bare metal` (in assembly and `c`). I need to calculate the clock cycles used to execute an assembly code. 
I am using the following code for PMU counter:

```
mov r0,#1 

MCR p15, 0, r0, c15, c12, 0 ; Write Performance Monitor Control Register 
  /* Reset Cycle Counter */ 

mov r0,#5 

MCR p15, 0, r0, c15, c12, 0 ; Write Performance Monitor Control Register 
  /* Meaure */ 

 MRC p15, 0, r0, c15, c12, 1 @ Read Cycle Counter Register 

<MY CODES> 

MRC p15, 0, r1, c15, c12, 1 @ Read Cycle Counter Register
```

From this if I have

```
add r3,#3
```

in place of my code i get `r1=8` and `r0=0`, which seems correct since arm11 has 8 pipeline stages and it takes 8 clock cycles to execute it.

But when I add more instructions I am getting ridiculous results like

```
add r3,#3

add r4,#1

r0=0,r1=97/96/94 (the result of r1 should also be constant!!!)
```

I am using `uart` to see results of registers on minicom.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, seeing the same thing, that is very interesting.

```
    @ nop
.globl test
test:
    mov r0,#1 
    MCR p15, 0, r0, c15, c12, 0 
    mov r0,#5 
    MCR p15, 0, r0, c15, c12, 0 
    MRC p15, 0, r0, c15, c12, 1 

    add r3,#3
    add r2,#1

    MRC p15, 0, r1, c15, c12, 1
    sub r0,r1,r0
    bx lr
```

I am calling this from C so if I muck with r4 in the code under test would have to save it on the stack so messed with r2.   Without the add r2 line the return value was 8 with the add r2 line the return value was 0x68 then 0x65.  Note this is on a pi zero.  So some clocks are a little faster than yours.

Remember this is running from dram and dram is painfully slow.  So you may be seeing some of that.

Initial alignment of the code:

```
00008024 <test>:
    8024:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
    8028:   ee0f0f1c    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr12, {0}
    802c:   e3a00005    mov r0, #5
    8030:   ee0f0f1c    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr12, {0}
    8034:   ee1f0f3c    mrc 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr12, {1}
    8038:   e2833003    add r3, r3, #3
    803c:   e2822001    add r2, r2, #1
    8040:   ee1f1f3c    mrc 15, 0, r1, cr15, cr12, {1}
    8044:   e0410000    sub r0, r1, r0
    8048:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

Yep if I uncomment the nop in front of .globl test, and I comment out the add r2 I only have the add r3 as the code under test, but the nop pushes the alignment of the whole block of code.  with the add r3 and no nop I get 8 counts with the add r3 and the nop I get 0x67 counts.

So I think this is just a case of measuring the fetch.  I have not enabled the arm cache, but there may be a deeper cache or an mmu or other since this ram is shared between the arm and the gpu.

If I go one step further and uncomment the nop have both the add r3 and the add r2 it is 0x69 counts.  or basically on par or barely longer than one instruction, so we forced a fetch in there.

so I my case if I add more nops so the initial read of the count is aligned on an 8 word boundary, and I have the two instructions being measured

```
00008030 <test>:
    8030:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
    8034:   ee0f0f1c    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr12, {0}
    8038:   e3a00005    mov r0, #5
    803c:   ee0f0f1c    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr12, {0}
    8040:   ee1f0f3c    mrc 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr12, {1}
    8044:   e2833003    add r3, r3, #3
    8048:   e2822001    add r2, r2, #1
    804c:   ee1f1f3c    mrc 15, 0, r1, cr15, cr12, {1}
    8050:   e0410000    sub r0, r1, r0
    8054:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

I get a count of 8.  I put a third instruction in there an add r3 and two add r2s.  still a count of 8.

If I go back to this where at least part of it is in a different fetch line.

```
00008024 <test>:
    8024:   e3a00001    mov r0, #1
    8028:   ee0f0f1c    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr12, {0}
    802c:   e3a00005    mov r0, #5
    8030:   ee0f0f1c    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr12, {0}
    8034:   ee1f0f3c    mrc 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr12, {1}
    8038:   e2833003    add r3, r3, #3
    803c:   e2822001    add r2, r2, #1
    8040:   ee1f1f3c    mrc 15, 0, r1, cr15, cr12, {1}
    8044:   e0410000    sub r0, r1, r0
    8048:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

And I do three runs without changing anything, and then enable the l1 cache (instruction) and do three more runs I get

```
00000068 
0000001D 
0000001D 
0000001F 
00000008 
00000008
```

So I think you are dealing with dram which is slow, fetch lines, cache misses and and hits and resulting cache line fetches.

If you were expecting to see the number of clocks it took to execute an instruction you wont, you dont have zero wait state memory unless you can keep the entire code under test in the l1 cache.

I dont think there is on chip sram that you can use for this kind of thing for this chip/board, you are going to end up hitting dram and that dram is shared with the gpu.  So basically program execution time is not expected to be deterministic and as with your computer or phone or other the cpu is not the bottleneck has not been for a long time it is sitting around waiting to be fed data or instructions.